# Exercise 9 Chapter IV Section 1 - T W Hungerford, Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

> If $f: A \to A$ is an R-module homomorphism such that $ff=f$ then $A = Ker(f) \oplus Im(f)$.

**My attempt :** Based on Theorem 1.18. Trying the canonical exact sequence determined by $0 \to Ker(f) \to A \to Im(f) \to 0$ and considering any element $y \in Im(f)$ it follows $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in A$. Now
$f(y) = f(f(x)) = f(x) = y$ since $ff = f$. Therefore $ff|_{Im(f)} = id|_{Im(f)}$. How to finish this if I am on the right track?

Exercise 9 Chapter IV Section 1 - T W Hungerford, *Algebra*.

Answer (score 1):

To complete your solution using exact sequences, note that you have shown that there is a homomorphism $h: Im(f) \to A$ (namely $h = f|_{Im(f)}$) such that $f h = 1|_{Im(f)}$. So, the exact sequence is a **split**.  So, $A = Ker(f) \oplus Im(f)$.

There are, however, simpler solutions. Here is one:

Since $ff =f$, for any $y \in Ker(f) \cap Im(f)$, there is $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$ and, since  $y \in Ker(f)$, we have $f(y)=0$. Putting all together, we have
$$y = f(x)= f(f(x)) = f(y)= 0$$
So $Ker(f) \cap Im(f)=\{0\}$.

Given any $x \in A$, note that $x- f(x) \in Ker(f)$. In fact,
$$f(x- f(x)) = f(x) - f(f(x)) = 0$$
It is clear that  $f(x) \in Im(f)$ and that $x = (x- f(x))+f(x)$.
So we have that
$A = Ker(f) \oplus Im(f)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)